# Import array to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
Array
(
    [AED] => United Arab Emirates Dirham
    [AFN] => Afghan Afghani
    [ALL] => Albanian Lek
    [AMD] => Armenian Dram
    [ANG] => Netherlands Antillean Guilder
    [AOA] => Angolan Kwanza
    [ARS] => Argentine Peso
    [AUD] => Australian Dollar
)
```

from a json decode and i want to import those to a mysql table like:

```
id \ code \ name
1  \  AED \ United Arab Emirates Dirham
2  \  AFN \ Afghan Afghani
```

and so on...

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach:

```
foreach($theArray as $key => $value)
{
  mysqli_query($link,"insert into table(code,name) values (".$key.",".$value.")");
}
```